# Blender crashes when using an EnumProperty to set Space

Tags: python, properties

I have a property that I'm trying to use to set the current `context.area.type`

Using the property as it is now, the `set_space` function crashes Blender. If I use the property with just an `update` function it works, but I need the property to also get updated when the `context.area.type` is changed in another manner by the user (using a `get`).

Can anyone please help me create this property so that its `set` method sets the current space? Thank you!

```py
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import EnumProperty

def set_space(self,value):
    if value == 0:
        bpy.context.area.type = "GRAPH_EDITOR"
    elif value == 1:
        bpy.context.area.type = "DOPESHEET_EDITOR"

class SWITCH_PG_switcher_props(PropertyGroup):
    space: EnumProperty(
        name="Space Target",
        description="Switch to space",
        items=(
            ('GRAPH_EDITOR', "", "Graph Editor", "GRAPH", 0),
            ('DOPESHEET_EDITOR', "", "Dopesheet Editor", "ACTION", 1),
        ),
        default='GRAPH_EDITOR',
        set = set_space
        )

def draw_enum(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
    layout.prop(scene.switcher, "space", icon_only=True, expand=True)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SWITCH_PG_switcher_props)
    bpy.types.Scene.switcher = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SWITCH_PG_switcher_props)
    bpy.types.DOPESHEET_HT_header.append(draw_enum)
    bpy.types.GRAPH_HT_header.append(draw_enum)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.switcher
    bpy.types.DOPESHEET_HT_header.remove(draw_enum)
    bpy.types.GRAPH_HT_header.remove(draw_enum)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SWITCH_PG_switcher_props)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Side effects in property callback methods is AFAIK not really supported in Blender, so the crash is not really surprising, especially since it concerns the context which is needed for pretty much every element of the UI. In this case what you want to achieve should be done with an [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) which are allowed to modify the data outside of their scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment so it's more clear hopefully.

Side effects in property callback methods is AFAIK not really supported in Blender, so the crash is not really surprising, especially since it concerns the context which is needed for pretty much every element of the UI. What I mean is property callbacks are not meant to be used to modify the state of other properties, especially not of Blender internal constructs. In this case what you want to achieve should be done with an [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) which are allowed to modify the data outside of their scope.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    space: bpy.props.StringProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        context.area.type = self.space
        return {'FINISHED'}

def draw_enum(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    for area_type, icon in zip (
        ("GRAPH_EDITOR", "DOPESHEET_EDITOR"), 
        ("GRAPH", "ACTION")):
            op = row.operator(
                "object.simple_operator", 
                text="", 
                icon=icon, 
                depress=context.area.type==area_type)
            op.space = area_type

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.DOPESHEET_HT_header.append(draw_enum)
    bpy.types.GRAPH_HT_header.append(draw_enum)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.DOPESHEET_HT_header.remove(draw_enum)
    bpy.types.GRAPH_HT_header.remove(draw_enum)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gorgious, thank you for the reply. I'd explored the method you're suggesting (thank you!), but opted for the other because it showed the active Space in the Header with a blue background. It sounds like it's acknowledged as a bug in Blender: https://developer.blender.org/T100519

For now I'm going with the method you mentioned, but hopeful that someone can explain how to work around this bug. Thank you, again, for your help!

Comment: @Dr.Pontchartrain you can indeed draw the buttons as pressed with the `depress` argument. I've updated the code in my answer :)

Comment: very nice! Thank you so much :D